# Custom class creating compilation problems

Tags: compiling, document-classes, preamble

I tried adding my preamble to a new class file called `labs.cls`, in the same directory as my `lab1.tex` file. I then changed the preamble of my tex file to `\documentclass{labs}`. When I try to compile the tex file, I get this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(F:\Coding\phy-182\formal_lab_reports\1_formal_lab\lab1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(F:\Coding\phy-182\formal_lab_reports\1_formal_lab\labs.cls
Document Class: labs 2014-03-16 Formal lab style for Miami University
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mh\mathtools.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mh\mhsetup.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\was\gensymb.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg")))
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   -
l.2

?
```

this is my class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{labs}[2014-03-16 Formal lab style for University]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\LoadClass[letterpaper]{article}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{gensymb}
\RequirePackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\fontsize{12}{14}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\linespread{2}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\lhead{Nathan Mara}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong in this class file?

I get the same error with even this tex file:

```
\documentclass{labs}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The date in the argument to `\ProvidesClass` must be `2014/03/16` (slashes, not hyphens).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commands `\ProvidesClass`, `\ProvidesPackage` and `\ProvidesFile` have a mandatory argument (the file name, without extension for the first two commands, because `.cls` and `.sty` are implied) and an optional argument stating the version of the file. The optional argument should be of the form

> `<date>` `<info>`

The `<info>` part is not required; if present it should be separated from the date by a space.

So, for instance, one can simply do

```
\ProvidesClass{foo}
```

which however is not good programming style: a date should always be provided. Hence either

```
\ProvidesClass{foo}[2014/03/19]
```

or

```
\ProvidesClass{foo}[2014/03/19 Some information]
```

Note that the format of the date is like shown, with slashes and not hyphens:

```
YYYY/MM/DD
```

that is, four digits for the year, two digits for the month and two digits for the day. Any other input will cause the `\ifnum` error.

Comment: thx for answer.  recently i ran a "missing = for ifnum" error with the gensymb package, and the last sentence in your answer explains why that happens: https://gitlab.com/kjhtex/gensymb/-/commit/7eae952310598e5c402aaf5377cb0979534a9a01 unluckily this fix was made two weeks ago, and MikTeX hasn't got the time to include this fix.